# Survival::Survfit (left, right, and interval censoring)

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

I'm attempting to estimate survival probabilities using the survfit function from the Survival package. My dataset consists of animals that were captured at various times over the course of ~2 years. Some animals died, some animals were censored after capture and some animals lived beyond the end of the study (I'm guessing this means I have left, right and interval censored data).

I can estimate survival probability using right censors only, but this assumes all animals were captured on the same day and does not account for adding new animals through time. What I would like to do is estimate survival as a function of calendar day and not as a function of time since capture.

Example data:

```
time1<- c(2, 386, 0, 1, 384, 3, 61, 33, 385, 64)
time2<- c(366, 665, 285, 665, 665, 454, 279, 254, 665, 665)
censor<- c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
region <- c(1, 6, 1, 6, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 6)
m1<- data.frame(time1, time2, censor, region)
```

code:

```
km.2 <- survfit(Surv(m1$time1, m1$time2, m1$censor, type = "interval") ~ m1$region)
```

Note the above code runs but doesn't estimate what I laid out above. I hope this is an issue of specifying certain arguments in the survfit function but this is where I am lost. Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you've figured this out by now since it was nearly a year ago.  I'm a bit confused by the experiment you're explaining.

However, one item that pops out immediately is the "time1".  **I believe you can't have any times start or end at 0.  I recommend adding 0.5 or 1 to that specific time observation, and explaining why in your write up.**  But having a 0 value is a likely culprit for why it's not estimating properly

Comment: Exactly why do you think that start times cannot be 0? This doesn’t really look like an answer. Suggest it be deleted and posted as a comment if you really think it’s accurate.